# Angular router not recognized in Visual Studio

Tags: angular, visual-studio, router

I'm doing a PluralSight course about integrating an ASP.NET Core RESTful API with an Angular frontend.
In the sample code I'm modifying I have a class that imports the Angular Router

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

and then injects it through the constructor:

```
export class CustomersComponent implements OnInit {
 ...
  constructor(private router: Router, 
              private dataFilter: DataFilterService) { }
```

Visual Studio marks the word Router in the constructor red, and displays the following error:

[image]

VS also offers two possible actions to resolve this:

[image]

However, the first option produces another strange state:

[image]

And the second option just moves the 'Could not find symbol' to the line where the import is added. Furthermore, neither option is consistent with the code presented in the course.

I'm new to Angular and have no idea what's going on here, and how to resolve this type of error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is a `discussion` tab provided for each course on Pluralsight. Consider also posting your question there. The author may be able to help you. I don't use Angular in Visual Studio, but as a guess, is `RouterModule` missing from your Angular module?

Comment: I don't think that's it. This sort of thing is happening throughout the project. For example in app.module.ts, in this import:
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'; the 'BrowserModule' bit is grey, VS claims it's unused. Then in @NgModule({  
imports: [    
BrowserModule is red and I get the same two 'options' to add import. But I can build and run the thing just fine. So... Yay! ... I guess. Must be some Visual Studio quirk.